# Determining the usage of a character style in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, character-styles

While working on a book layout on InDesign (2019 version), I've made some experiments with character styles. Thus, I've created an empty character style in order to use it for marking the part of a chapter title that should appear in the automated running header (thanks to a text variable).
Then I have changed my mind and don't use that trick anymore. However, when I try to delete the now unused character style, the app asks me what I want to substitute it with, as if it was still used somewhere in the file.
I have checked everywhere:

- GREP styles
- nested styles
- "based on" feature in other styles
- text variables

but cannot find any reference to this style I want to delete.

Does anyone have any idea on where else I could look for it?

Answer (score 4):

As the character style is "empty" as you say, you could just replace it with *[None]* without any consequence, but I guess you ask this for the principle of it.

Here is a complete list of what I would check. I also include things you have already mentioned for the sake of completeness.

- Search the document for any occurrences of the character style:

  [image]

  Select the character style with the *Specify attributes to find* button, make sure that *Include Locked Layers and Locked Objects*, *Include Locked Stories*, *Include Hidden Layers and Hidden Objects*, *Include Master Pages* and *Include Footnotes* are turned on and perform the search.
- Check every *Character Style* to see if any of them is *Based On* the character style you want to delete.
- Check every *Paragraph Style* to see if the character style is used in *Drop Caps*, *Nested Styles*, *Nested Line Style*, *GREP Style* or *Bullets and Numbering*.
- Check *Type > Text Variables* of the *Running Header (Character Style)* type.
- Check *Type > Document Footnote Options*.
- Check *Type > Document Endnote Options*.
- Check *Layout > Table of Contents*.
- Lastly remember that a paragraph can be styled to use *Drop Caps*, *Nested Styles*, *Nested Line Style*, *GREP Style* or *Bullets and Numbering* even though it isn't saved in a *Paragraph Style*. You could have pressed *Break Link to Style* for a paragraph or, you could have manually made changes to a paragraph which makes it use the unwanted character style without it being reflected in any *Paragraph Style*.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE Artemij! I hope you can use my answer.

Comment: What about the fridge? 

Comment: @Danielillo, lol! I already looked under the bed, but I don't think a fat character style would fit there.

Comment: @Wolff thank you for this exhaustive answer. I already checked almost all the items you suggest. Not the last one though, so I will try.
I even tried to export the file as XML and read it on a text reader. There where some strange tokens concerning the running headers, but I am not able to find them when I open the file on InDesign.

Comment: @ArtemijKeidan, any reason why you can't just delete the character style and replace it with *[None]*?

Comment: @Wolff no special reasons, probably I'll do so, I just hate when computer apps behave unpredictably